# Redirect user based on roles (without running OnGet)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-roles

Users for my ASP.NET Core application have different roles. And different roles have access to different pages.

I've implemented policies and correctly authorized various folders for the related roles.

But I also need to redirect some users to a different area so they see the pages they are supposed to instead of just getting an Access Denied error.

I know I can use `User.IsInRole()` from my regular Index file and redirect them to the correct pages, but I think I'd prefer that they can never even load a page they don't have access to. And I'd prefer to disable my regular Index file to these users altogether.

How would I do this? Is this already supported using policies, etc.? Or do I need to write some sort of middleware?

Comment: i think this is opinion based question. as for me, Index + OnGet (or method in controller) is the easiest option

Comment: @YehorAndrosov: Yes, it's easier. But it means I can't set a policy to prevent such users from access my regular page altogether. So I'm asking how to do it a different way. I've reworked my question to be clearer.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, have you considered using a hateoas approach?  An initial call to your API to get the allowed actions for a user/role.

Comment: @PeteGO: This isn't an API. Just regular pages.

Comment: The policies just determine you're authorized or not ,you need to try with filter/middleware/Custom the behavior of Authorize Middleware the document  related : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-6.0